# Databound HyperlinkButton event not working in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The following code is not working:

```
private void fileNameLinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HyperlinkButton clickedLink = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
    string uri = String.Format(
        "/IsolatedStorageListing;component/SecondPage.xaml?id={0}",
        clickedLink.Content);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
}

<ListBox Height="183"
     Width="460"
     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     Name="fileListBox">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <HyperlinkButton Name="fileNameLinkButton"
                                 Content="{Binding}"
                                 Click="fileNameLinkButton_Click" />         
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I click the HyperlinkButton, my app closes/exit. Please help!

Comment: the exception message and the line where the code is failing might help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you need to add `/IsolatedStorageListing;component` in the navigation `Uri`. Try to remove it and simply leave `/SecondPage.xaml?id={0}`

By the way, it is really strange and moreover wrong to use `Content` for navigation parameter. I would suggest you to use `Tag` property for such purposes.

Comment: I have removed but its not navigating to my SecondPage.xaml, instead the app exit.

Comment: could you run application in Debug mode and let us know where and what kind of exception crashes your app?

Comment: Its working now, I have remove "/" before the page name. Thanks!